# How can I add a role to a member

Tags: discord.js

So I am trying to make a verify script so when a member join he/she has to write !verify and then he/she will get a rank on the discord so we won't get raided by bot's

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    
    message.delete()
    
    const member = message.author
    let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("791724979435470889")

    if (!message.channel.name.startsWith(`⚜ʙɪᴇɴ`)) return message.channel.send(`you have already been verified`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
    message.channel.send(`${member} have been verifyed`).then(member.roles.add(myRole).tehn(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })));
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "verify" //Name of the command
}
```

And when I try this code out I get this error And I have tried to research it but I can't find anything on it

This is my error

```
message.channel.send(`${member} have been verifyed`).then(member.roles.add(myRole).tehn(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })));
                                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\utility\verify.js:12:76)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\index.js:257:33)
    at Client.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lauri\Desktop\QuebecCity\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`roles` is a property of the GuildMember object. You are unable to add roles to a User object (AKA message.author that returns the user object of the author of a message). From that instance, we would simply want to instead use the `member` property of the `message` object, resulting in `message.member`.

#### Final Code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    
    message.delete()
    
    const member = message.member
    let myRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get("791724979435470889")

    if (!message.channel.name.startsWith(`⚜ʙɪᴇɴ`)) return message.channel.send(`you have already been verified`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
    message.channel.send(`${member} have been verifyed`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
    member.roles.add(myRole)
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "verify" //Name of the command
}
```